# ASP.NET Menu Problem With .swf file

Tags: asp.net-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET Menu Problem With .swf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237716/asp-net-menu-problem-with-swf-file)

I have a problem in ASP.NET Menu with Flash file.
i have added a .swf file into my asp.net webpage, when ever i view the menu it goes behind the .swf file.Could you plz tell me how to solve this problem...
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your flash object is put onto the page (post your code if you haven't resolved it) but usually you can fix this problem by setting the `wmode` parameter to `transparent`. Here is a link to the [object/embed tag information](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html) from Adobe.

Add the following to your object tags:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

If you use something like [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to load your flash, you can set the wmode value in the javascript that loads the swf. Here's a rough example using there documentation:

```
var flashvars = {};
var params = {
    wmode: "transparent"
};
var attributes = {};

swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Comment: (+1) And you can even you use wmode:"opaque"