# ASP.NET Menu Problem With .swf file

Tags: asp.net, flash

I have a drop down menu and a swf file on an asp.net page. When the menu drops down it is behind the swf file when it should appear in front.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the following parameter to the OBJECT tag:

   `<param name="wmode" value="transparent">`
2. Add the following parameter to the EMBED tag:

   `wmode="transparent"`

(Taken from the [Adobe site](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14201.html))